# Why jquery return [object][object] value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: browser image]

Problem: **When output is Getting that time value in text box is [object][object]**

Jquery code:

```
    function EditDirectWarping() {
    var dwviewmodel;
    dwviewmodel =
     {
         DirectWarping: {

             DispoNo: 12346,



         }
     }
    CallAjax("/Production/Get_DirectWarpingData", "json", JSON.stringify(dwviewmodel), "POST", "application/json", false, DirectWarping_CallBackMethod, "", null);
}


function DirectWarping_CallBackMethod(data) {

    $("#txtgrosswt").val($(this).val(data.DirectWarping.Gross_Wt)),

    $("#txtnetwt").val($(this).val(data.DirectWarping.Net_Wt)),

    $("#txtwarpingmachine").val($(this).val(data.DirectWarping.Warping_Machine)),

    $("#txtwarpingmachinespeed").val($(this).val(data.DirectWarping.Warping_Machine_Speed)),

    $("#txtprogramcheckedby").val($(this).val(data.DirectWarping.Program_Checked_By)),

    $("#txtprogramgivenby").val($(this).val(data.DirectWarping.Program_Given_By)),

    $("#txtoperatorremark").val($(this).val(data.DirectWarping.Operators_Remark)),

    $("#txtwastage").val($(this).val(data.DirectWarping.Wastage)),

    $("#txtjumbobeammtrs").val($(this).val(data.DirectWarping.Jumbo_Beam_Mtrs)),

    $("#txtpressurerollpressure").val($(this).val(data.DirectWarping.Pressure_Roll_Pressure))

}
```

**When output is Getting that time value in text box is [object][object]**

Comment: ...and the question is?

Comment: where is the function which gives you `[object][object]` value??

Comment: Use the console to view the values

Comment: From the controller value is returning but in text box showing [object][object] and CallBackMethod is a function

Comment: @GauravAggarwal controller function?

Comment: @Gerard i want value in text box not in console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When JavaScript prints `[object Object]`, it means you are trying to output an object instead of a string or number.

To display a date object as a string, use:

```
theDateObject.toString();
```

Comment: but where i am using date in code? and every filed value in int not in string

Comment: Nowhere in your example code, you only mention time in your question, which is normally represented by a `Date` object. Try to debug `data` to check if all the values you use are strings or numbers and not objects.

Comment: no no, actually i want to say that when showing output its show [object object], u forget about time. and i debugged i am getting all field value in viewmodel. but on screen its showing [object object]. see i am upload image in question

Comment: Yes, it means you use objects for the values, which can't work. Try to `console.log` all the values that you pick from the `data` response

Comment: Sorry, I see the mistake now. You set the value of the inputs to `$(this)....`. That returns an object. Remove that and only set it to `data.xxx`.

Comment: Like: `$("#txtnetwt").val(data.DirectWarping.Net_Wt)`

Comment: i want to update my data using jquery, so is this correct syntax in jquery for updating data for example :- Net_Wt: $("#txtnetwt").val()                                   because i am using this one but not data updated. so can you help me with correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

As a example

Instead of this:

$("#txtnetwt").val($(this).val(data.DirectWarping.Net_Wt)),

**Write this(correct answer):
$("#txtnetwt").val(data.DirectWarping.Net_Wt)**

Answer (score 0):

The conversion of string to object returns [Object object] so instead use:
**$.trim(yourObjectOrElement.val())**

This .val() returns a string ;